# Elasticsearch fuzzy query - max_expansions

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 5+, I did some queries using fuzzy.
I Understood about the follows fuzzy parameters:

fuzziness, prefix_length.

But, I can not understand about "max_expansions", I read many articles, but it is hard to me because there are fews examples about it.

Can you explanation me about this parameter using examples? How it works together fuzziness parameter?

Write an example:
I did this query:

```
GET my-index/my-type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "fuzzy": {
      "my-field": {
        "value": "house",
        "fuzziness": 1,
        "prefix_length": 0,
        "max_expansions": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have 4 shards, my query found 6 results, because there are 6 documents with "hous" in the "my-field".
If max_expansions it is like as limit in database, the max result should be 4 (because I have 4 shards)? Why return 6 results?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quote from [Elasticsearch blog post](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search):

> The `max_expansions` setting, which defines the maximum number of terms the fuzzy query will match before halting the search, can also have dramatic effects on the performance of a fuzzy query. Cutting down the query terms has a negative effect, however, in that some valid results may not be found due to early termination of the query. It is important to understand that the `max_expansions` query limit works at the shard level, meaning that even if set to 1, multiple terms may match, all coming from different shards. This behavior can make it seem as if `max_expansions` is not in effect, so beware that counting unique terms that come are returned is not a valid way to determine if `max_expansions` is working.

Basically it means that under the hood in one step when Elasticsearch is triggering fuzzy query it is limiting the number of terms considered in search to the `max_expansions`. As it was written it is not so obvious as for example `limit` in databases because here, in Elasticsearch it is working on shards. Probably more expected results you will have setting up Elasticsearch only with one shard locally and testing the behavior.

Comment: Hi @Piotr Pradzynski, I edited my post, I tried to do an example to understand that you said. Can you give an example?

Comment: I did test using your explanation, like you said, the ES works with this value per shard, I could understand now, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Hi I am not able to infer the actual meaning of max_expansions. Since the shards  are set to 4 and max_expansions is set to 1, 1 fuzzy match per shard should be part of the result and hence the total match should be 4. But the results found is 6? The reason I am asking is I am facing a very similar issue. WIth this issue, I am facing another,  i set max_expansion to 75, yet it could not match two results present on two different indices(each with two shards).